# Dreamweaver type templates in Aptana

Tags: templates, aptana, dreamweaver

I am designing a very small website using basic HTML. I usually use a CMS but it has been a while since I did just HTML files, I was wondering if there was some sort templating where you can have like areas like a "Master template" and when a section is changed or added to the rest of the HTML pages that have those sections change with it. Like a common header and footer so I don't have to make the changes in each page if I need to make a change to an element.
I am using AptanaStudio 3 and was wondering if there was a feature like that as there is in Dreamweaver. I don't have Dreamweaver installed on my new computer, so taht is not an option.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try server-side includes (SSI): http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341/SSI-The-Include-Command.htm